# Interpretation of Goals relative to Visits and Pageviews in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I am stumped on some of the data I am seeing.

The image below summarizes the data that I am pulling from the API into Tableau.

[image]

In GA, we have the URL goal setup for the page shown.  I am confused on how the following situation exists:

1. How can 121 visits generate 483 pageviews and 420 goals (unique pageviews)?

The way that I interpret the results:

- the url shown was seen over 121 visits but viewed 420 unique times.

I simply don't get how that is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Given this data, even I was inclined to come to the same conclusion. However, I think Tableau is mixing up visit level and page level metrics. [Avinash Kaushik has recently written a kick-ass post](http://www.kaushik.net/avinash/hits-sessions-metrics-dimensions-web-analytics/) on this common error.

I would still go to GA and double check this data in Site Content->All Pages Report.

Comment: Thanks for your post. I did confirm that my data are as reported in GA (custom reporting, however).  While the post obviously hammers home the point of taking caution when mixing session and hit level data, I don't understand why the metric visits can't be used with page.  Wouldnt the interpretation be "this page was viewed in 121 visits?"

Comment: Yes, the interpretation would most likely be that. However, then that means the pageviews you see is for those visits and not for that page.